# Updating foreign key within transaction fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, h2, consistency

I have a table A referencing table B via a compound foreign key (we use Quartz which has compound keys).
When I want to update the compound key I have to update it for both tables, but:

- when I start with table A, it fails because there is no valid foreign key in table B.

  when I start with table B, it doesn't allow me to update it as table A still references the records.

I always though that I should be able to do this within transaction as data is consistent before and after transaction, but I couldn't get it working on Postgres and H2.

What's wrong with my understanding of transactional consistency?

Answer (score 0):

First insert valid key in `B`. Then update `A`. Finally delete the invalid key in `B`.

Comment: I already know this solution, but I would like to know why those 2 approaches don't work

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use a deferred constraint for the foreign key.
The problem you are having is because Postgres will check foreign key constraints after each statement, not after the transaction is complete. Deferred constraints allow you to defer checks for constraints until the end of the transaction.

This article helped me when I ran into the same problem and it also has examples similar to your situation. Give it a read and you should know how to solve this:
https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html